# Bootstrap/React - populate select options with array

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to use Jquery to populate the options list for my dropdown. However below code does not populate the options as expected.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
render() {
        return (
//blah blah
<select id="pm-list" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.state.selectedApprover} onChange={(event) => this.state.selectedApprover = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].value}>
    {(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.approvers.length; i++) {
            $('#pm-list').append('<option value=' + this.state.approvers[i] + '>' + this.state.approvers[i] + '</option>');
        }
    })()}
</select>
)};
}
```

Probably I used it at wrong place?

**UPDATE**

I am able to resolve it after putting the Jquery piece inside the `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    //blah blah
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.approvers.length; i++) {
        $('#pm-list').append('<option value=' + this.state.approvers[i].NtId + '>' + this.state.approvers[i].FullName + '</option>');
    }
};
```

But what is the rationale behind this though?

Comment: Are you able to link the full component code? You don't need jquery for this sort of thing when using React

Answer (score 0):

### My Suggestions to improve the code

1. `onChange` function use `this.setState()` instead of `this.state.selectedApprover =`
2. You have to write the `jquery` things inside `componentDidMount` function.
3. **The Major Thing** why using `jquery`? you can simply implement this using `jsx` expressions.

Try This :

```
<select id="pm-list" className="form-control" defaultValue={this.state.selectedApprover} onChange={(event) => this.setState({selectedApprover: event.target.value})>
    {() => {
        return this.state.approvers.map((approver) => {
            return (
                <option value="{approver}">{approver}</option>
            )
        })
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I realised your Point 2 before I read your answer. But I will accept it any way. Regarding your Point 3, can you show some sample code?